# Why is this code to programmatically create a content type failing?

Tags: nodes

```
<?php

            function news_article_install() {

                // Define node type
                $news_article = array(
                    'type' => 'news_article',
                    'name' => 'News Article',
                    'base' => 'node_content',
                    'description' => 'A news article content type',
                    'body_label' => 'Article Text',
                    'custom' => 1,
                    'title' =>  1,
                    'title_label'   =>  'Headline'
                );

                // Save content type
                $news_article = node_type_set_defaults($news_article);
                node_type_save($news_article);
                node_add_body_field($news_article);
            }


?>
```

Edit: I've simplified the function as much as possible, still having errors. The errors now are...

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in _node_types_build() (line 689 of /Users/ryan/Sites/Drupal/modules/node/node.module).
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in _node_types_build() (line 689 of /Users/ryan/Sites/Drupal/modules/node/node.module).
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in _node_types_build() (line 689 of /Users/ryan/Sites/Drupal/modules/node/node.module).
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in _node_types_build() (line 689 of /Users/ryan/Sites/Drupal/modules/node/node.module).
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `node_type_save` and `node_add_body_field` in the wrong order. You can always steal ideas from http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/profiles--standard--standard.install/function/standard_install/7

Comment: Thanks, I based my current revision on what I found there. Still having errors, though - do you have any additional insight?

Comment: Also - where is the API documentation for this? The hook_install page just lists what this does - where is the info on what items should be in the node_type array, what typically goes on during an install, etc.

Comment: Dump the variable used on line 689.